# Query about hyperplane in SVM

Tags: computational-geometry, machine-learning

I am a beginner in Machine Learning. I was reading through basics of SVM and read this definition:

> The goal of a support vector machine is to find  the optimal
>   separating hyperplane which maximizes the margin of the training data.

Now, when I observed the examples, in a 2D plane, a straight line was being considered as a separator for data. Now, my query is that how is a straight line a hyperplane if each coordinate that describes the line is two dimensional. Unless hyperplane refers to observation of the equation that describes a curve, I dont understand how it works. If so, could someone please give a good explanation of hyperplanes.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a hyperplane?

Comment: `In geometry a hyperplane is a subspace of one dimension less than its ambient space`

Comment: Yes, or a translation of such a subspace. So if the ambient space is $\mathbb R^2$, then a hyperplane is just a line.